# Searching user returning 200 response but data is not present in AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm facing an issue in AD B2C graph query, using following filter,

```
"$filter=signInNames/any(x:x/value eq 'xxxx.zzz+14@something.something.xx.xx')"
```

I'm writing this question because, getting issue only with above email formats, if the email id is like this **something@digital.com**, then there is no problem Graph API is returning result properly. The result getting from API is

```
{
  "odata.metadata": "https://graph.windows.net/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/$metadata#directoryObjects",
  "value": []
}
```

Using **api-version** of **1.6**.

Is there any issue with the email address or any solution for this? Thanks

Comment: Can you please give a clear view about your Email format and please give  error details with request id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test it in my side with the same format email you provided and also get the `"value": []` as the result. According to some further test, it was caused by the `+` symbol in your email address. We need to encode the email address and then set it in the filter of the api, it works fine. You can copy the email address and go to this [page](https://www.urlencoder.org/) to do the encode operation.

Below is my test steps:

I create an account with the email `xxxx.zzz+14@something.something.xx.xx`.
[image]

After encode the email and request the graph api again, it can response the result.
[image]